# Create View must be only statement in batch

Tags: sql-server, database

I keep getting the error that create view must be the only statement in the batch, and I tried using go and doing Use database but it still is not working. Please help! TY

```
 CREATE VIEW questionfiver
     AS
    SELECT line.inv_number,line.line_number,line.prod_code,line.line_units,line.line_price,line.line_amount
    FROM LINE
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PROD_CODE=LINE.PROD_CODE
    WHERE
    and PRODUCT.PROD_INDATE>= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH);
```

Comment: You have an extraneous `AND` after `WHERE`. Also, `CURDATE()` and `DATE_ADD` are not SQL Server functions. Perhaps you intended `GETDATE()` and `DATEADD`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using MYSQL functions in SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE PRODUCT.PROD_INDATE >= DATEADD(MONTH,18,GETDATE())
```